# How can I use system defined regional number format settings for an eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, locale, number-formatting, rcp, region

My system's default region is nl_BE and I want my RCP applcation to use the region's number format settings defined at the OS level. How can I get my RCP app to read the system specific settings ?

I tried launching the application with vm arg -nl nl_BE but it takes '.' as a thousand grouper and not space/' ' (which is defined in the system region settings at  os level.

Comment: Eclipse RCP just uses the standard Java `Locale` support for number formats and the like.

Comment: `-nl nl_BE` is not a VM arg. In the ini file it has to be specified via two separate lines `-nl` and `nl_BE` at the top or above `-vmargs` and `-vm`.

Comment: Is there a way to customise standard java locale support to use ' ' space instead of '.' ? @greg-449

Comment: I'm not really an expert on the details of Locale. If you are formatting the numbers yourself you can use `DecimalFormatSymbols` with `DecimalFormat` and control everything.

Comment: Ya.. I tried doing that but it didn't take effect for some reason. @greg-449